# Data files with names that contain numbered indices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got 100 data files.  The names of the files are data0001.dat, data0002.dat,data0003.dat,...,up to data0100.dat (notice that there are 4 digits in the numbering of a file name starting from 0000).

There is a numeric stored in each of these data files, for instance x58 in data0058.dat.

I would like to generate a list of these x's, namely [x1, x2,...,x100]. I tentatively wrote the following code in Python 3 to implement my goal:

```
xList= []
while n <= 100
      filename = ''data0000'+n.dat' # It seems Python doesn't recognize this line, my intention is to import here the file data(0000+n).dat
      L = open(filename,'r')
      x= fromfile(L, the x value)
      coordinates = xList.append(x)
     return xList
```

How to properly type the filename for the n-th data file 'data0000+n.dat' in my loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using Python version >= 3.6, but here we go:

```
filename = 'data0{:03}.dat'.format(n)  # for python < 3.6
filename = f'data0{n:03}.dat'  # for python >= 3.6
```

Both of these pad zeroe(s) on the left to make the desired strings.
so the whole code will be

```
xList= []
while n <= 100
    filename = 'data0{:03}.dat'.format(n) # Use one of two methods defined above.
    n += 1
    L = open(filename,'r')
    x= fromfile(L, the x value)  # not sure what this does
    xList.append(x)
print(xList)  # return if you are using these in a function
```